# How to create header and footer for multiple pages in 'borb'?

Tags: python, pdf, borb

I'm using Borb for Python. I can’t find in the examples or documentation how to create a header and footer for multi-page documents. I would also like the footer to indicate the current page of all. Can someone share an example?

https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#93-creating-a-stunning-flyer
There is an example here with creating a footer, but it doesn’t say how to place it on several pages

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in the answer

This is a quick little test I wrote to add page numbers to a `Document`

```py
import random
from _decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import Alignment
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Lipsum
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle
from tests.test_case import TestCase


class TestAddPageNr(TestCase):

    def test_add_page_nr(self):

        doc: Document = Document()

        # seed random
        random.seed(1024)

        # add initial Page
        p: Page = Page()
        doc.add_page(p)

        # PageLayout
        layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(p)

        # add content
        for _ in range(0, 20):
            layout.add(Paragraph(Lipsum.generate_lipsum_text(5)))

        # get the number of pages
        number_of_pages: int = int(doc.get_document_info().get_number_of_pages())

        # iterate over each Page
        for page_nr in range(0, number_of_pages):
            page: Page = doc.get_page(page_nr)

            # add page nr
            # do this in the utmost right corner
            Paragraph(f"page {page_nr+1} out of {number_of_pages}",
                      horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT,
                      vertical_alignment=Alignment.BOTTOM).paint(page, Rectangle(
                page.get_page_info().get_width() - Decimal(100),
                Decimal(0),
                Decimal(100),
                Decimal(20)
            ))

        # save
        with open(self.get_first_output_file(), "wb") as in_file_handle:
            PDF.dumps(in_file_handle, doc)
```

The key here is the following code:

```py
        # get the number of pages
        number_of_pages: int = int(doc.get_document_info().get_number_of_pages())

        # iterate over each Page
        for page_nr in range(0, number_of_pages):
            page: Page = doc.get_page(page_nr)

            # add page nr
            # do this in the utmost right corner
            Paragraph(f"page {page_nr+1} out of {number_of_pages}",
                      horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT,
                      vertical_alignment=Alignment.BOTTOM).paint(page, Rectangle(
                page.get_page_info().get_width() - Decimal(100),
                Decimal(0),
                Decimal(100),
                Decimal(20)
            ))
```

This code gets the number of `Page` objects currently in the `Document`.

The loop below it then gets each `Page` in turn, and adds content to it (a `Paragraph`) at a fixed location (the bottom right corner).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that in MultiColumnLayout you can use footer_paint_method: (Any, Rectangle) -> None | None = None and header_paint_method: (Any, Rectangle) -> None | None = None. What are they for then?

Comment: You can use those. They represent any method that will get called before/after rendering the Page. However, at that point in time the total number of pages is not yet know. So you would be unable to print something like "Page 3 of 5". You would however be able to print "page 3".